# swiftui state variable count lost what it stored

Tags: swiftui, state

when I click onTapGesture event to setup

```
  self.showDetailView = true
  self.count = 5
```

the sheet will popup,  but the self.count always be `0`, not be
`5`.
so the code  `Text("5555")` will never be hitt.

it seems state variable count lost what it stored.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showDetailView = false
    @State var count = 0
    var testArr = [1,2,3,4,5]
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List(testArr.indices){ indice in
                Text("row num \(indice)")
                    .onTapGesture{
                        
                        self.showDetailView = true
                        self.count = 5
                        }
                
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$showDetailView) {
                    if self.count == 0{
                        //  print("count = 0")
                    }
                    if  self.count == 5{
                        Text("5555")
                    }
                
                }
            
                .navigationBarTitle("Your Reading")
        }
        }
    }

    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Binding` to pass value to child view:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var count: Int

    var body: some View {
        if count == 5 {
            Text("5555")
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }

    }
}
```

in your `.sheet`:

```
.sheet(isPresented: self.$showDetailView) {
    if self.count == 0 {
        //  print("count = 0")
    }
    DetailView(count: $count)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

another approach is this:

```
class CountModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var count: Int = 0
    init(_ c: Int) { self.count = c }
}

struct ContentView: View {

@State var showDetailView = false
@ObservedObject var model = CountModel(0)
var testArr = [1,2,3,4,5]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(testArr.indices) { indice in
            Text("row num \(indice)")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.model.count = 5
                    self.showDetailView = true
                }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$showDetailView) {
            if self.model.count == 0 {
                let _ = print("count = 0")
                Text("0000")
            }
            if self.model.count == 5 {
                let _ = print("count = 5")
                Text("5555")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Your Reading")
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution will still work if you change @Published var count: Int? = 0

Comment: I have created another post,  which maybe different issue. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639269/how-to-deal-with-swiftui-state-optional-unwrap